# How to handle this popup?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

[image]

The above pic consist of my popup image, Can anyone guide me how to handle this pop up?

Comment: It's not clear what *handle* means in your context. Is the popup unexpected?

Comment: Yes it unexpected, but we need to handle this pop up, when I say handle, I am able to click leave or stay button.

Comment: @Gopal, can you clarify what browser you are using? Are you actually using both Watir-Webdriver and Watir-Classic? They are very different implementations.

Comment: Right now I am automating in Chrome and I will be automating in Firefox as well. Can you suggest me how to click this window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This popup can be treated like any other alert. You can confirm the dialog (ie click Leave) using:

```
browser.alert.ok
```

If you do  not know if the popup will or will not be there, you can add a check for its presence:

```
browser.alert.ok if browser.alert.present?
```

If this does not work, an alternative is to disable the function being called on unload. Make sure that you override the function before it is triggered.

```
# Remove the function
browser.execute_script("window.onbeforeunload = null")

# Then trigger the action that leaves the page
browser.link.click
```

Comment: I tried but it throws this error `C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:70:in assert_ok': unknown error: cannot determine loading status (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
from unexpected alert open
  (Session info: chrome=52.0.2743.116)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)`

Comment: You need to call the script before the action that opens the alert, not after the alert is generating. At any rate, executing JavaScript to prevent the dialog creation is probably the wrong choice (ie could have various unexpected risks). The best solution is to actually interact with the popup, which can be done using the Alert API (see updated answer).

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. But browser.alert.ok doesn't work here.

Comment: Interesting, `browser.alert.ok` worked for the page I was testing on. Are you saying that you went with executing the script to override the unload?

Comment: Yes, I executed the script to override the unload, it works fine.